# Why does the new Gmail address not show on the Samsung tab 2 version 7.0?

Tags: gmail

A friend forgot her primary Gmail address so I created a new one for her. The reason she could not find it was her surname was wrong. The problem is that when I press the Gmail icon on her Samsung tab 2 version 7.0 only the primary email inbox is shown. I have found no way to view the new Gmail address which she needs to open to confirm something she did on the internet.

Is there any solution given on the web, perhaps from Google? I completely fail to understand why Google will not allow us to change what the primary address is. We shall never use the one Google has decided upon against our wishes. The only inbox we are interested in opening is that of the new Gmail address I have just created.

Comment: I want to access the inbox of the new email address so we can read the emails that have been sent there in connection with applications for membership cards we have made on the web. Should I copy this question and paste it on Android Enthusiasts instead? I am totally incompetent regarding technical matters and things like tags and did not know there was any other place to ask my question than this one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone's `Settings`. Under `Accounts`, add the existing Google account. After you go through the wizard (and making sure email is synced), go back to the GMail app. When you trigger/click the hamburger menu, you should be able to select between your different GMail accounts.